# How To Use D[ ] to Define a System of PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

We have two variables $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ which are functions of $x,t$. That is, $u_{1}=u_{1}(x,t)$ and $u_{2}=u_{2}(x,t)$. Consider the the system of partial differential equations $$\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial x}=u_{2},\\\frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial t}.$$

Next, consider the transformation $$w_{11}=u_{1},\quad w_{12}=\frac{u_{1}}{u_{2}}.$$ We need to compute $\frac{\partial w_{1k}}{\partial x}$ for $k=1,2$.

In Mathematica my process is very manual. I am basically using Mathematica to simplify the partial derivatives that I have found using pen and paper. The code is as follows.

```
(*f[k] denotes the partial derivative of u[k] with respect to x*)
(*g[1] denotes the partial derivative of u[1] with respect to t*)
f[1] = u[2];
f[2] = g[1];

trans = {u[1] -> w[1, 1], u[2] -> w[1, 1] w[1, 2]};

(*Denote y[1,1] as the partial derivative of w[1,1] with respect to x*)
z[1, 1] = f[1] /. trans

(*Denote y[1,2] as the partial derivative of w[1,2] with respect to x*)
(*Denote z[1,1] as the partial derivative of w[1,1] with respect to t*)
z[1, 2] = Factor[(u[2]^2 - u[1] g[1])/u[2]^2 /. trans] /. g[1]->g[1,1]
```

I would like to compute the partial derivatives of $w_{1k}$ using a single code as opposed to doing it separately. I tried using the built-in function $D[\;]$, but run into problems when defining, for example, $\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial x}=u_{2}$ using $D[\;]$. In Mathematica:

```
D[u[1][x, t], x] = u[2][x, t];

Set::write: Tag D in \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(\(u[1]\)[x, t]\)\) is Protected. >>
```

I guess my main problem is how to define the system $\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial x}=u_{2},\;\;\frac{\partial u_{2}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u_{1}}{\partial t}$ in Mathematica that will allow me to use $D[\;]$. Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we define your system of equations:

```
eqns = {D[u1[x,t],x] == u2[x,t], D[u2[x,t],x] == D[u1[x,t],t]};
```

Then we solve your substitution for `u1` and `u2`:

```
sub = Solve[{w11[x, t] == u1[x, t], w12[x, t] == u1[x, t]/u2[x, t]},
            {u1[x, t], u2[x, t]}]

(* {{u1[x, t] -> w11[x, t], u2[x, t] -> w11[x, t]/w12[x, t]}} *)
```

Then we transform the variables into the correct functional form:

```
sub = sub /. {(f_[var__] -> e_) :> (f -> Function[{var}, e])}

(* {{u1 -> Function[{x, t}, w11[x, t]],
     u2 -> Function[{x, t}, w11[x, t]/w12[x, t]]}} *)
```

Finally we can make the substitution:

```
eqns /. sub

( *{{Derivative[1, 0][w11][x, t] == w11[x, t]/w12[x, t], 
     Derivative[1, 0][w11][x, t]/w12[x, t] -
      (w11[x, t]*Derivative[1, 0][w12][x, t])/w12[x, t]^2 == 
      Derivative[0, 1][w11][x, t]}} *)
```

---

In order to interpret this result, you'll need to know a little about the `Derivative` operator.  In a form like this:

```
Derivative[3][f]
```

It represents the third derivative of a function `f` with one argument.  It does partial derivatives like this:

```
Derivative[3,2][g]
```

This represents `g` differentiated three times with respect to its first argument, and differentiated two times with respect to its second argument.

So, to take an example from your transformed system:

```
Derivative[1, 0][w11][x, t]
```

Is equivalent to:

$$
\frac{\partial w_{11}}{\partial x}
$$

Comment: Thanks. For the `UpSet` how can I write the output produced by `D[w11[x, t], x] (* u2[x, t] *)` purely in terms of w11 and w12?

Comment: @Jack It wasn't clear to me that you wanted the whole system in terms of `w11` and `w12`... I've changed my answer to hopefully do the transformation you want.